# Swift Currency Format ISO Standard Conversion Issues

Tags: ios, swift, currency

After reading the Apple Documents for NSNumberFormatter [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/locale) I'm trying to convert currency as per the Uber API Documentation.  Both documentations state that they use the ISO formatting standard, however in my code I find this to not be the case.  ISO 4217 Standard [here](http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php)
 and at ISO [itself](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/currency_codes.htm)

```
public static func convertStringCurrencyToNumber(strCurrency:String, locale:String)->Double {
    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "\(locale)")
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    println(formatter.numberFromString(strCurrency))
    if let converted:Double = formatter.numberFromString(strCurrency)?.doubleValue {
        return converted
    }else{
        return 0.0
    }

}
```

My Unit Test for this function

```
func testCurrencyConversion() {
    let fiveBucks = UberReceipt.convertStringCurrencyToNumber("$5.00", locale: "en_US")
    println(fiveBucks)
    let tenBucks = UberReceipt.converStringCurrencyToNumber("$10.00", locale:"USD")
    println(tenBucks)
}
```

Console Log:
Optional(5.0)
nil
5.0
0.0

If I use "en_US" the result is as expect, which would be 5.0, however if I use what Uber returns as the locale "USD", the return value is 0.0.  Upon printing/inspecting what happens when the formatter converts the currency, I find that it returns nil.

I find the documentation misleading in regards to what it says about formatter.locale = NSLocale(...).  According to the docs "The locale determines the default values for many formatter attributes, such as ISO country and language codes, **currency code**...."

I was under the believe that setting the locale **should** also set the currency code.  Is this incorrect?  Why then does my code work if I use the non-standard "en_US" code as apposed to the ISO code (which is supposed to be what Apple Documentation uses) "USD"

Comment: The ISO currency code is `USD`. There's no locale code `USA`. Local codes for USA include `en_US` (English) and `es_US` (Spanish) among others. If the Uber API is doing what you described, it's wrong.

Comment: Even after my terrible oversight of USA instead of USD,  I replaced it with USD and it still prints 0.0 and 'nil' for formatting conversion and "en_US" still works perfectly.  The Uber API does in fact return USD I apparently just can't read and my mind automatically turned it into USA.  However, there still seems to be an issue with my code and I'm not sure why it will not accept USD as the locale string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static func convertStringCurrencyToNumber(strCurrency:String, locale:String)->Double {
    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.currencyCode = locale
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    if let converted:Double = formatter.numberFromString(strCurrency)?.doubleValue {
        return converted
    }else{
        return 0.0
    }
}
```

Changing formatter.locale to formatter.currencyCode works as expected with the ISO 4127 Country and Currency code "USD".

Answer (score 0):

As Zoff Dino said, USD is not a valid locale identifier. To get the complete list you can run:

```
NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers()
```

You are correct in that setting the locale sets the currency code. Try for example:

```
let l = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "de_CH")
let f = NSNumberFormatter()
f.locale = l
f.currencyCode // Playground shows CHF
```

**Locale** defines the correct alphabetical order, thousands separator, time and date formats, currency code and other things. What you are passing in is not a locale, but currency code. If you wanted to construct locale from currency code, you could create a lookup table from the output of `NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers()` and resulting currency codes.

It might help if you clarify what exactly is the API returning and what exactly you want to do with it.

Comment: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217, USD is a valid locale identifier.  I also corrected my post to reflect the changes.  Previously I was using locale 'USA', which is incorrect.  If you review the chart, it is number 840.  Also at http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/currency_codes.htm, it specifically states United States dollars can be represented as the code 'USD'.  I am having difficulty understanding why the documentation from Apple states it uses ISO 4217 (which is a 3 letter alphabetical code) not a 4 alphabetical code.

Comment: Also note, according to iso.org, ISO 4217 is built off of / extends ISO 3166 which is a two letter code system.  Again, everyone is replying that Apple uses 'en_US' as the ISO standard, which, correct me if I am wrong, is a violation of ISO 4217, as defined on their website as being "The first two letters of the ISO 4217 three-letter code are the same as the code for the country name, and where possible the third letter corresponds to the first letter of the currency name." - iso.org

Comment: I think I am not conveying what I want to accomplish.  I wish to have a function that takes in the string formatted as: "$4.00" or any valid currency string and a locale setting using the ISO 4217 3 character code.  func example(currency:String, locale:String).  Example: func example("$4.00", "USD").  **USD** is a valid locale in regards to ISO 4217.  I believe the Apple documentation is misleading in the fact that it requires it to be set to "en_US" which derives to "USD".  My revised question is, can the locale recognize the standard 3 letter country and currency code?

Comment: Furthermore, using the "en_US" as the locale identifier is, in my opinion, misleading.  "en_US" as defined in ISO 8859-15 is a "8-bit single-byte coded graphic character sets".  To me, this is defining the available character codes.  The "$" is part of said character set.  But again, it's misleading especially since the Apple documentation makes mention of ISO 4217 as the output from println(f.currencyCode).

Comment: Finally (sorry for the multiple posts, I'm limited to a certain amount of characters per response), am I to believe that the Apple documentation means to use the ISO 8859-15 to set the "locale".  Example. f.locale = "en_US".  Then this code runs through their magic and outputs another ISO standard -> "USD"?  If that is the case, is their another way to reverse the derivation to instead go from ISO 4127 -> ISO 8859-15.  Example f.someFunctionToSetLocale = "USD" which derives to "en_US"?

Comment: I think you are confusing locale with currency code. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html

Comment: I suppose I am. The point still remains that "en_US" defines a character set of 8 bits. Not very intuitive wording I suppose on the documentation. Anyway, I'll try setting just the currency code and see if that works in the AM and will post the results. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/currencyCode